# I’m confused about “anonymous iOS memory”

Tags: iphone, ios

I have three ways of writing this code. The third way confuses me.

#### First way works fine.

```
//.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
//.m
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"allen.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
UIImageView *t = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
self.picImageStage = t;
```

#### Second way works fine.

```
//.h
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
//.m
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"allen.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
self.picImageStage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

#### Third way turns wrong.

```
//.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
//.m
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"allen.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
self.picImageStage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

I don’t understand the reason. Could anyone help me? Thanks :D

Comment: why you're using [NSString stringWithFormat:] when there is no format? You can do just: `NSString *name = @"allen.png";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the **3rd snippet** you have declared the **@property as weak**, and the UIImageView will be ***deallocated immediately***. Because a weak relationship will be nil'd when there is no strong relationship to the same object.

In the **1st snippet**, which is almost the same, you assigned the UIImageView to a local variable first. This **local variable uses a strong relationship** implicitly. If you leave the scope of the local strong variable (i.e. the method where you run this code) the property will be deallocated too, except if you create another strong assignment before leaving the scope of the variable. Which will for example happen if you add the UIImageView as a subView of another view. Adding a view to another creates a strong relationship.

Answer (score 4):

Let's examine all three, because that might be the easiest way to explain this to you.

> Number 1

```
//first method
//.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
//.m
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"allen.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
UIImageView *t = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
self.picImageStage = t;
```

You're initializing a local variable UIImageView with a retain count of +1.  Because weak properties don't call implicit retains on their values, you don't own the value stored in self.picImageStage, which means you're one lucky camper because as soon as the function that declares that local UIImageView passes out of scope, your variable is deallocated.

> Number 2

```
//second method
//.h
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
//.m
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"allen.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
self.picImageStage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

This one gets into those implicit retains I was talking about.  The compiler expands this line:

```
self.picImageStage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

out to

```
self.picImageStage = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image]retain];
```

Meaning that you own it, and are free to do with it what you please.

> Number 3

```
//third method
//.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
//.m
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"allen.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
self.picImageStage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

Not only are you assigning to a weak property from a variable that you don't own, as soon as the assignment is called, your variable won't store the value!  It's because, again, weak pointers do not call implicit retains on their assignments, meaning you have no control over how long the variable sticks around, and I'm willing to bet that it doesn't stay alive for very long!

Comment: +1 for your elaborate answer , the answer is the before you ,so thank you  again.:D

Answer (score 2):

Here you use `weak` property instead of `retain` and also alloc it directly with UIImage...

Also in first stage when you assign UIImageView to the `picImageStage` then its work fine because its directly equal and store in the `picImageStage`.. thats the difference..

if you use

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
```

instead of

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
```

then its work fine with this reason..

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @MatthewKennedy  yes dude but i just want to say which you post in your answer dude.. but its also right , yes dude??

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
//.h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picImageStage;
//.m
NSString *userName = @"allen";
NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",userName];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
[self.picImageStage setImage:image];
```

Comment: @VakulSaini I guess the original code requires this (e.g. the image is set according to the username), so I copied it.

Comment: But this is just single line - :) `NSString *name = @"allen.png";` or  `NSString *name = [NSString stringWithString:@"allen.png"];` is okay. Anyways NP... !!